# Convergence of the complex series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{z+n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I don't have familiarity with complex series.
I know this series won't converge if $z$ is a negative integer. Apart from that, I know that the series does not converge absolutely (because the absolute value gets close to $\frac{1}{n}$ which diverges).
If instead of complex number $z$ I had $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then:$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{x+n}$$
Would converge for all $x$ apart from negative integers, due to the Leibniz test. Can I use the same argument for a complex number $z$?
I'm not sure about what to do because I have never dealt with alternating complex series before.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have time to give a full answer. But both the real parts (rather easily) and imaginary parts alternate and satisfy the requirements for the typical Alternating Series Test. So you can rework the standard alternating series test argument to work here as well.

Comment: You could also just mimic the proof for Dirichlet's test.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to write

$$\frac{1}{z+n} = \frac{1}{n} - \biggl(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{z+n}\biggr) = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{z}{n(z+n)}.$$

For $n \geqslant 2\lvert z\rvert$, we have $\lvert z+n\rvert \geqslant n - \lvert z\rvert \geqslant \frac{1}{2}n$, so

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z}{n(z+n)}$$

converges absolutely. Then the convergence of

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z+n} = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{z+n} = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}z}{n(z+n)}$$

for all $z$ that are not non-positive integers follows with the Leibniz criterion. In fact the convergence is locally uniform.